# NullPointerExceptions when finding Parentnode in tree

Tags: java, tree, parent

I'm trying to write a method, which returns the parent node of a given node.

```
public BinarySearchTreeNode<T> getParent(BinarySearchTreeNode<T> e) {
    if (e == null) {
        return null;
    }
    BinarySearchTreeNode<T> current = this.root;
    T eValue = e.getValue();
    while (current != null) {
        if (howManyChildren(current) == 0) {
            return null;
        } else if (eValue.equals(current.getLeft().getValue())
                || eValue.equals(current.getRight().getValue())) {
            return current;
        } else if (eValue.compareTo(current.getValue()) < 0) {
            current = current.getLeft();
        } else {
            current = current.getRight();
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

However I receive NullPointerExceptions, when one or both of the children are null-nodes and equals tries to compare the value with null.
How do I go on to fix this? I'm still new to Java.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to check that the children are not null before you call a method on them.  In this case you call `current.getLeft().getValue()` but the left child might be null.  If it's null you will get the NullPointerException.

The following is an example with checking to make sure they aren't null before calling the method.  Caveat, I didn't check to see if the entire code was correct besides the NullPointerException.

```
public BinarySearchTreeNode<T> getParent(BinarySearchTreeNode<T> e) {
    if (e == null) {
        return null;
    }
    BinarySearchTreeNode<T> current = this.root;
    T eValue = e.getValue();
    while (current != null) {
        if (howManyChildren(current) == 0) {
            return null;
        } else if ((current.getLeft()!=null && eValue.equals(current.getLeft().getValue()))
                || (current.getRight()!=null) && eValue.equals(current.getRight().getValue())) {
            return current;
        } else if (eValue.compareTo(current.getValue()) < 0) {
            current = current.getLeft();
        } else {
            current = current.getRight();
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

Comment: Such a simple solution... I guess I'm pretty tired if I wasn't able to think of this myself. Thanks a lot. It works.

Answer (score 0):

With object variables, when the value is `null` there is no object there that can supply the methods you would be calling.

You compare an object variable's value to `null` with:

```
if (obj == null) {
    ... do whatever ...
}
```

You can compare an object to null in many cases like this:

```
if (obj.equals(null)) ...
```

or

```
String s = null;

if (obj.equals(s)) ... this works
if (s.equals(obj)) ... this doesn't work
```

**Note**

In your code, if the node you are searching for is the root, it will never find it.

Similarly, you check all the children to see if they match and then you decide which of the children could match by comparing the value to the parent. Maybe you should reorder things a bit so you test the current node

If it's null, the search has ended in failure
If it matches, return its parent which you saved on the last iteration.
If it doesn't match, get the correct child -- right or left -- based on the value and loop.

This has the advantage that you only get the value of nodes when you know they aren't null.

```
T eValue = e.getValue();

BinarySearchTreeNode<T> prev = null;
BinarySearchTreeNode<T> current = this.root;
while (current != null) {
    int compare = eValue.compareTo(current.getValue());
    if (compare == 0) {
        return prev;
    }

    prev = current; // save the parent in case it matches
    if (compare < 0) {
        current = current.getLeft();
    } else {
        current = current.getRight();
    }
}
```